# Null value breaking the custom filters in Mat Table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm adding multiple custom filters to Mat-Table.

Issue is when the data is have an `null` value entire filter functionality is breaking.

My Sample Mock

```
{
  name: null,
  id: 1,
  colour: 'Green',
  pet: 'Dog'
},
```

In `customFilter()` function I'm filter the data like below,

```
 data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.name) !== -1
```

I tried adding like this `data?.name` but no luck.

Link to my Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-column-filter-ov6ut6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More elegant condition:

```
(data.name || '').toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.name.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let names = [
    {
  "name": null,
  "id": 1,
  "colour": "Green",
  "pet": "Dog"
},
       {
  "name": "Hello",
  "id": 2,
  "colour": "Green",
  "pet": "Dog"
},
        {
  "name": "Not null",
  "id": 3,
  "colour": "Green",
  "pet": "Dog"
}
];

let filterArray = names.filter((name1) => {return name1.name && name1.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('ello') > -1});
console.log(filterArray);
```

You have to add a null check and index of check in your filter condition.